# Can't create handler inside thread when getting location GPS data in Xamarin

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, gps

I have implemented a method that gets the device location GPS data. The thing is that when I run the application from the main thread, that is by launching the application manually on my mobile, it displays me the correct GPS data.

But I have implemented a background service that should keep running on a separate thread. This service should get me the GPS data.

So basically, when I instantiate the following `LocationGPS data = new LocationGPS()`, the location GPS data should be obtained, as the GPS logic is embedded in the constructor of the class itself. The partial code  within a new thread is here:

```
 Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Task.Run(async () =>
                    {             
                        LocationGPS data = new LocationGPS();
                    });
                });
```

However on debug mode, I get the following error:

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called
>   Looper.prepare()

Also, what I have understood is that the location method has to explicitly run on the UI thread.

Could someone help me to handle this error so as I get the location GPS data correctly in the background service ?

Comment: Mixing `new Thread` and `Task.Run` make no sense.  And you don't need any of that if you use async.

Comment: @SLaks : Yes, but I do not want my UI to be blocked while the background service is running, even in the event I want to launch the app manually. I want two processes to be doing the same job without blocking each other.

Comment: If you use async, that won't happen.

Comment: Even if both processes are calling the same methods simultaneously ? Calling same methods and querying the db and inserting data into the db simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

As per android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) :

> If a LocationListener is used but with no Looper specified then the
>   calling thread must already be a Looper thread such as the main thread
>   of the calling Activity. If a Looper is specified with a
>   LocationListener then callbacks are made on the supplied Looper
>   thread.

So, if your plan is to run the location listener on a separate thread, you need to create a [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) thread.

Comment: I have invoke the method within the DeviceBeginOnMainThread, and it works. Thanks though.